# Bootstrap 4.3 - splitting a form across columns

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, forms, twig

I'm working on a checkout page/form in a pseudo-Amazon style - payment options in a column on the left, subtotal and submit button in a column on the right.  The problem is, a `<form>` element is a block element, which causes some real headaches with my layout.  My current page template (Twig):

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="row">
        <form action="{{ url('_checkout') }}" method="post">
            <div class="offset-md-1 col-md-7 mt-4 mb-5">
                <h2>Select Payment Option:</h2>

                {% for key, choice in choices %}
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="card" id="card{{ loop.index }}" value="{{ choice }}">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="card{{ loop.index }}">{{ key }}</label>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <div class="offset-md-1 col-md-2 mt-4 mb-5">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-burnt-orange">Place Your Order</button>
                <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ csrf_token('somesecretvalue') }}">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

CSS is stock Bootstrap with a custom color for my submit button.

The result looks like (CC values are Stripe test values, and the name for the user is fake, so no security issues in the screenshot):

[image]

Which is definitely not what I want.

Is it possible to split a form the way I want?

Comment: Could the form be on the outside of the row div?  Or, keep the form around the payment option and use JavaScript to trigger the submit (you could have a JavaScript-hidden button in the form to allow degradation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was actually really simple.  Since `<form>` is a block element, it constrains what's inside of it.  Because Bootstrap's layout classes depend on those elements to be placed within a containing element with the `row` class, having just a  `<form>` element means they won't work.  The solution is to remove the container `<div>`, since it's superfluous in this context, and simply give `<form>` the `row` class instead:

```
<form class="row" action="{{ url('_checkout') }}" method="post">
    <div class="offset-md-1 col-md-7 mt-4 mb-5">
        <h2>Select Payment Option:</h2>

        {% for key, choice in choices %}
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="card" id="card{{ loop.index }}" value="{{ choice }}">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="card{{ loop.index }}">{{ key }}</label>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="offset-md-1 col-md-2 mt-4 mb-5">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-burnt-orange">Place Your Order</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ csrf_token('checkout') }}">
        {# TODO: figure this out - display subtotal and 'Place Your Order' button #}
    </div>
</form>
```

This way, the `<div>` elements that have Bootstrap's layout classes actually behave properly.